# PersistedModel.create(Array) returns an object with numbered properties

Tags: typescript, loopbackjs, angular-loopback

Below is a snippet of code that calls a Loopback API method with an array of values. The input values are correct, no errors are thrown on the API and the subscribe block runs as expected.

```
    const newStudentGroups =
            selectedStudentIds.map(sId => ({
                studentId: sId,
                groupId: this.group.id,
                schoolId: this.curSchool.id,
                programId: this.curProg.id,
            }));
   this.stuGroupApi.create(newStudentGroups)
       .subscribe((newStu) => {
          console.log(newStu.map(s=>s[0]));
       });
```

However the values returned to the subscribe block as newStu appears as an object of the form:

```
{ 
  0:{
     studentId: 123,
     groupId: 321,  
     schoolId: 1,
     programId: 5
    },
  1:{
     studentId: 132,
     groupId: 322,  
     schoolId: 1,
     programId: 5
    },
  2:{studentId: 143,
     groupId: 331,  
     schoolId: 1,
     programId: 5
    }
}
```

I need an array of StudentGroup objects the same as I put in. I recognize that I can forkJoin individual calls to the API but that seems like a lot of network traffic vs a single call that could/should run as a batch on the DB.

I can't find much to suggest if I've done this wrong or if there's a canonical way to get this back into the form in which I sent it. Is this a bug? Am I running the call incorrectly?

EDIT: I've been inspecting the actual network requests and it looks like Loopback is actually returning the array as required. So this has to be the SDK on my end somewhere. Does @mean-expert/loopback-sdk-builder convert arrays to objects intentionally or did I misconfigure something? I'm on version"@mean-expert/loopback-sdk-builder": "^2.1.0-rc.10.5".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated Answer

TL;DR
Use the `createMany` function instead of `create`.

Given way that @mean-expert/loopback-sdk-builder parses the responses in BaseLoopBackApi (it should be in `services/core`), calling the `create` method will attempt to parse the response back to the generic datatype for the service (maybe StudentGroup for your call?). However, this parsing will by default use `Object.assign(this, data);`. This will unfortunately convert arrays into objects the way you show.

e.g.

```
Object.assign({}, ['hi', 'there'])
```

will yield

```
{ '0': 'hi', '1': 'there' }
```

However, @mean-expert/loopback-sdk-builder provides another default function to fix that issue for you. Just switch your call to use `createMany` instead.

Hence:

```
const newStudentGroups = selectedStudentIds.map(sId => ({
    studentId: sId,
    groupId: this.group.id,
    schoolId: this.curSchool.id,
    programId: this.curProg.id,
}));
this.stuGroupApi.createMany(newStudentGroups)
   .subscribe(newStus => {
      console.log(newStus);
   });
```

### Original Answer

Given the response from the server, you can get a usable array back by running

```
this.stuGroupApi.create(newStudentGroups)
   .map(newStu => Object.keys(newStu).map(i => newStu[i]))
   .subscribe((newStu) => {
      console.log(newStu.map(s=>s[0]));
   });
```

Comment: This works, but I'd rather get the return correct, instead of correcting it afterwards.

Still, it does solve the problem if that's all there is.

Comment: Updated to reflect actual fix using SDK library.

Comment: So it's a kinda-sorta bug, since it does what I want but gives back a poorly formatted answer.

createMany worked, eliminated the Object.keys mapping. This is the answer